# How to access elements in a JSON decoded associative array PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm new to php, and I'm wording how to return an associative array of JSON data type? So here's my php code:

```
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

// echo the JSON (you can echo this to JavaScript to use it there)
//echo $JSON;

// You can decode it to process it in PHP
$data = json_decode($JSON,true);
var_dump($data);
```

Here's a snippet of what the data looks like when I dump it to the screen:

```
array(2) {
["product"] => array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(7) { 
        ["styles"]=> array(13) { 
            [0]=> array(7) { 
                ["price"]=> string(6) "$64.95" 
                ["productUrl"]=> string(46) "http://www.zappos.com/product/7515478/color/25" 
                ["percentOff"]=> string(2) "0%" 
                ["styleId"]=> string(7) "1788226" 
                ["imageUrl"]=> string(65) "http://www.zappos.com/images/z/1/7/8/8/2/2/1788226-p-DETAILED.jpg" 
                ["color"]=> string(6) "Almond" 
                ["originalPrice"]=> string(6) "$64.95" 
            }
```

Now how would I go about accessing the first array element? 
I've tried:

```
echo $data[0][0]['orignalPrice'];
```

and it does not work. Could someone please help? Also is there a decent debugger for php on a mac? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Word of advice, when you `print_r()` something in HTML, use "page source" before you copy/paste.

Comment: _“How to access elements in a JSON decoded associative array PHP”_ – in the same way, as if the array was _not_ “coming from JSON”. And if you don’t know how to do _that_ – then you should go read up on some basics first.

Comment: ok cool thanks, It's kind of annoying that you can't debug problems like these. Is there a way to do such thing? I have a mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that `$data['product'][0]['styles'][0]['originalPrice']`

Would also recommend you to have a look on a documentation, to learn more about [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Comment: so how would you suggest I for loop each item of price in the array?

Comment: @user3124081 I guess using foreach loop. `foreach ($data['product'] AS $product) { echo $product['styles'][0]['originalPrice']; }`
`